# TCP vs HTTP in Bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, nodes, full-node

Why does bitcoin use TCP instead of creating a web server and using HTTP to comunicate between the nodes?

What's the advantage of using TCP over a HTTP server?

Is that important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Http is a protocol that works on TCP.
So if you have an http-server, it uses TCP to communicate anyway.
The better question would be "Why should they use an http-server if they don't need it?".

They don't need/want to show a website. They just want to send binary information easily and want to be sure that the other peer received it completly/correctly. And TCP is the perfect protocol for that.